# Python function with two overloads calls another one with the same overloads - explain to mypy

Tags: python, mypy

How do we explain to mypy that this code is ok?

```
from typing import overload, Union


@overload
def foo(x: float, y: str):
    ...

@overload
def foo(x: list, y: tuple):
    ...

def foo(x: Union[float, list], y: Union[str, tuple]):
    bar(x, y)  # type error!


@overload
def bar(x: float, y: str):
    ...

@overload
def bar(x: list, y: tuple):
    ...

def bar(x: Union[float, list], y: Union[str, tuple]):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

The type errors are:

```
foo.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "bar" has incompatible type "Union[float, List[Any]]"; expected "float"  [arg-type]
foo.py:13: error: Argument 2 to "bar" has incompatible type "Union[str, Tuple[Any, ...]]"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

In similar cases I would use `TypeVar`, but the problem is that here `x` and `y` are different (but correlated) types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: Combine related types

If it is possible to change `foo`'s  signature, then we can describe the type relationships to mypy as follows:

```py
@overload
def foo(xy: Tuple[float, str]):
    ... 

@overload
def foo(xy: Tuple[list, tuple]):
    ... 

def foo(xy: Union[Tuple[float, str], Tuple[list, tuple]]):
    bar(*xy)

# bar and its overloads unchanged
```

### Solution 2: Secretly combine related types

If we can't change `foo`'s signature, then as far as I can tell, this is an example of a situation that cannot at present be completely captured by mypy's type system<sup>1</sup>. Still, we can keep the amount of code excepted from type-checking to a single line

```py
@overload
def foo(x: float, y: str):
    ... 

@overload
def foo(x: list, y: tuple):
    ... 

def foo(x, y):        # no type annotations, so...
    foo_impl((x, y))  # ...this line is not type-checked

def foo_impl(xy: Union[Tuple[float, str], Tuple[list, tuple]]):
    bar(*xy)          # passes type-checking

# bar and its overloads unchanged
```

If `foo` is a single line, then we can achieve a similar result by simply removing type annotations on the signature of the implementation of `foo`

```py
@overload
def foo(x: float, y: str):
    ... 

@overload
def foo(x: list, y: tuple):
    ... 

def foo(x, y):  # no type annotations, so...
    bar(x, y)   # ...this line is not type-checked
```

### Keeping information about type correlations

Intuitively, the initial type annotations of the arguments of `foo` can be thought of as jointly specifying the type

```py
Tuple[Union[float, list], Union[str, tuple]]
```

which discards the information about the correlation between the type of `x` and the type of `y`. We can keep that information by "transposing" `Tuple` and `Union`, i.e. by saying

```py
Union[Tuple[float, str], Tuple[list, tuple]]
```

which preserves the information about the correlation. Both solutions above achieve this preservation in slightly different ways.

---

<sup>1</sup> There do exist type systems sophisticated enough to describe the above situation. For example, in C++ one can describe correlations between types using [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: *"# no type annotations, so...this line is not type-checked"* I had no idea that mypy would accept this. Thanks.